# Angular 6 + jQuery + fullpage.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, fullpage.js

I am trying to use fullpage.js without ngx-fullapge and I am facing some issues relating to imports:

First it seems that jquery does not work, even though the package is setup...

In a very simple `AppComponent` class definition I have:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import * as fullpagejs from 'fullpage.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ],
})
export class AppComponent  implements OnInit {
  public items = [1, 2, 3];

  public ngOnInit() : void {
    $('#fullpage')
  }
}
```

with a very simple template:

```
<div id="fullpage">

  <div class="section" id="landing">
    Landing
  </div>

  <div class="section" *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index" id="document_{{ i }}">
    Document {{ item }}
  </div>

  <div class="section" id="general-information">
    General Information
  </div>

</div>
```

And the `angular.json` has the scripts below:

```
 "scripts": [
          "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "./node_modules/fullpage.js/dist/jquery.fullpage.min.js"
        ]
```

And I have the error below:

```
ERROR
Error: $ is not a function
```

I created an online project here that reproduces the issue: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nrrujn

How can I use both jQuery and fullpage.js in this project?

[EDIT]

jQuery works with `import $ from 'jquery';` but the `fullpage()` method from fullpage.js still cannot be found.
I updated the stackblitz:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nrrujn

Comment: Try adding `declare var $: any` to the AppComponent.

Comment: Now fullPage.js is available for Angular: https://github.com/alvarotrigo/angular-fullpage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update Nov 2018:

Now fullPage.js is available for Angular: 
https://github.com/alvarotrigo/angular-fullpage

---

Not an expert on Angular but... perhaps you should declare $ on the window object after importing it?

What about this?

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import jQuery from 'jquery'; // <--- change here
import * as fullpagejs from 'fullpage.js';

if(!window.$){
    window.$ = jQuery;
}
```

Comment: `import jQuery as $ from 'jquery';` is a syntax error. It doesn't even make sense to rename the default export. You ARE giving it a name.

Comment: @LazarLjubenović agreed, this can be tested in the https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nrrujn

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have `jquery.fullpage.min.js` file present in the directory  `'./node_modules/fullpage.js/dist/jquery.fullpage.min.js'`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This post seems to be your first answer, and it contains code. Remember, you can add code blocks with markdown syntax and it seems much better. Check out [this help center article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 1):

The line `import * as $ from 'jquery';` is definitely correct.

Make sure that jquery is actually installed in your project. Run `npm install jquery@latest` to install it. Then remove it from the `scripts` array because it doesn't belong there.

Comment: tried to reset to the latest version and remove the paths in the scripts... but same old =/

Comment: @EhouarnPerret Try looking in your package-lock.json file. Is jquery in there? and is it the right version?